Migrating from CRA to Vite: Uncaught TypeError: Unable to determine current node version
Migrating from CRA to Vite for a react project. After running the vite project, it displays a blank page. There's a console error:
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to determine current node version
    at versionIncluded (index.js:51:9)
    at isCore (index.js:68:28)
    at node_modules/resolve/lib/core.js (core.js:9:21)
    at __require2 (chunk-LK32TJAX.js?v=b6f66255:18:50)
    at node_modules/resolve/index.js (index.js:2:14)
    at __require2 (chunk-LK32TJAX.js?v=b6f66255:18:50)
    at node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js (index.js:5:17)
    at __require2 (chunk-LK32TJAX.js?v=b6f66255:18:50)
    at index.js:43:1

The project runs fine with CRA. Cannot understand the issue here, also can't find a solution online. Here's my Vite config:
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import svgrPlugin from "vite-plugin-svgr";
import envCompatible from "vite-plugin-env-compatible";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  envPrefix: "REACT_APP_",
  build: {
    outDir: "build",
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: "/src",
    },
  },
  plugins: [react(), envCompatible()],
});


Tried updating dependencies using npm, also installed the latest versions of npm and node but nothing seems to work.

Let's take a look at your stack trace.  The issue appears to be originating in babel-plugin-macros.  Is babel-plugin-macros a dependency that you have in your project or is it a child dependency of some other dependency?
